# exception while sorting data grid column "Object must be of type Double." after changing the value

Tags: vb.net

I've a data grid `gridDetails` with columns `discount` and `total` filled from the database

`Total` is readonly while `discount` is not. When the value of discount is changed, The total is recalculated as

```
gridDetails.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value -= (Val(gridDetails.Item(2, e.RowIndex).Value))
```

after changing the value the column cant be sorted. it generates an exception

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message="Object must be of type Double."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Double.CompareTo(Object value)
       at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.RowComparer.CompareObjects(Object value1, Object value2, Int32 rowIndex1, Int32 rowIndex2)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.RowArrayList.Pivot(Int32 left, Int32 center, Int32 right)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.RowArrayList.CustomQuickSort(Int32 left, Int32 right)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.RowArrayList.CustomSort(RowComparer rowComparer)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Sort(IComparer customComparer, Boolean ascending)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SortInternal(IComparer comparer, DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, ListSortDirection direction)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Sort(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, ListSortDirection direction)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at cableguy.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

i've converted the result to double using Cdbl, DirectCast etc.. no hope
like 
`gridDetails.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value = Cdbl(gridDetails.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value-Val(gridDetails.Item(2, e.RowIndex).Value))`

any idea??

Comment: Finally got it to crash. I am going to take a swing at this. You probably have dots instead of commas. It's the only way I can get it to fail the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what @WozzeC explained is the reason... am adding wht i've done to make it alright.. Before adding to grid i've converted the values to Double. Now its okei.. :) :happy:

read the data to a datareader and

```
 While data.Read = True
  Dim total_amount As Double = data("discount")
  Dim discount_amount As Double = data("total")
  gridDetails.Rows.Add(total_amount ,discount_amount)
 End While
```

Answer (score 3):

Right, this is what I think is happening.
When you load the data from the database it is displayed as strings in the table. This way it's sortable and everything is fine. Then you go and change a value with your subtraction (quite possibly the first row). This alters the sorting to become based on doubles instead. Since your entire table is displayed with strings it crashes.

So basically, eiter make really sure that you insert doubles into your Datagridview from the beginning, convert the all the values in the column after you loaded your table or insert the updated value as a string.

Comment: I should also add that if you use a class (with attributes discount and total) and a bindingsource instead of table then this would never happen. I would also recommend you to have 3 columns instead of 2. This way you can have subtotal, gross total and discount. Now, once you update total, the original value is lost.

Comment: I was about to answer my question.. :D Thankz Wozzec... Tht is exactly the problem. I just converted it before adding to grid and it works fine..

Comment: Just tripped over this. The dgv sort method can't even manage to sort integers and bytes in the same column. It seems that every item in a column must be exactly the same type if you want to sort it

Answer (score 2):

if you are adding doubles, decimals, etc. to a gridview and you need to add a zero where there is no value be sure to use Ctype:

```
If IsNumeric(drs.Item("qty")) then
   dgvX.row(I).cell(0).value = CType(drs.Item("qty"), decimal)
Else
   dgvX.row(I).cell(0).value = CType(0, decimal)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            foreach(DataGridViewRow rowV in gridVerifyedData.Rows)
            {
                rowV.Cells["Tot_Work_hours"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(rowV.Cells["Tot_Work_hours"].Value);
            }
                gridVerifyedData.Sort(gridVerifyedData.Columns["Tot_Work_hours"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```