# Sort datagridview column type int64?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, columnsorting, int64

I have a single datagridview column and I want it to be sorted by number type **int64** (201905161102, 201905161101, 201905161103, 201905161102 ..)

I've tried :

```
datagridview.Sort(datagridview.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Descending)
```

But I have :

> object must be of type int32

Best I can see online, I need to convert the column or cell to an integer value type - but I'm not sure how to do so and if that's the **best method**.

I add rows to my columns collection like this:

```
 Dim rqt_histo1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `example` FROM `fiche_bilan` WHERE `id_patient`=" & id_patient, New MySqlConnection(ConnectString))
 rqt_histo1.Connection.Open()
 Dim rs_histo1 As MySqlDataReader
 rs_histo1 = rqt_histo1.ExecuteReader
 If rs_histo1.HasRows <> 0 Then
    While rs_histo1.Read()
        my_datagridview.Rows.Add(rs_histo1(0))
    End While
 End If
 rs_histo1.Close()
 rqt_histo1.Connection.Close()
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76efbdfb-1f6f-4803-9722-af0461807eee/error-quotobject-must-of-type-int32quot-trying-to-sort-on-column-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols this might help, not a solution but same error and could lead to you finding what is wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080575/exception-while-sorting-data-grid-column-object-must-be-of-type-double-after also try this

Comment: Please show how you are adding the Column to the columns collection and how you are adding the Rows to the rows collection.

Comment: I can only reproduce this if I add a 32bit integer to the dgv before adding 64bit values. Oddly enough though, If I add the values above and then add a new row with a 32bit value I receive `object must be of type int64` so it appears when mixing int32 and int64 this is occurring. The only way I can get it to not thow the error is to so something like `dgv.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt64(12244))` So are you adding 32bit values to the grid before any 64bit values?